# What are the semantics of the modulus operator?

Tags: c#, arrays

There was a piece of code in C# for Programmers 2010 that I was wondering about, here it is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < deck.Length; i++)
{
    deck[i] = new Card(faces[i % 13], suits[i / 13] );
}
```

I understand that count is the slot in the arrays memory, and that new Card is putting the suits and and faces in the deck and they return the count amount. What I don't understand is how can you modulus and divide into zero? Or am I misunderstanding? Thanks

Comment: So if I am getting this right, if you are doing modulus right, it should only do 1,2,3... until it goes to 13, then it repeats. Then what about the division? Wouldn't a modulus be good for that then? Why did they use division for the second?

Comment: I am talking about in the suits.

Answer (score 4):

This question sounds like the modulus operator is confusing you. The modulus (`%`) operator calculates the remainder from a division. It is structured the same as division (numerator / denominator). It appears that you see `i % 13` as `remainder of 13/i`. That is wrong. It is `remainder of i/13`. So if `i` is zero, the modulus operator will return 0. You are ***never*** dividing my zero in ***that*** application.

An example is `3/2`. `3/2` is 1 and half. But if you save that result to an integer (no decimal), only `1` is saved. Where did that half go? It was thrown away. If you want it, you could have saved it as a `float` or `double`, or used the modulus operator. `3%2` will give you `1`, the remainder. Here is an example program:

```
struct ModulusHelper
{
    public int Quotient;
    public int Remainder;
    public ModulusHelper(int numerator, int denominator)
    {
        Quotient = numerator / denominator;
        Remainder = numerator % denominator;
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ModulusHelper mod = new ModulusHelper(args[0], args[1]);
        Console.WriteLine("Quotient:  {0}", mod.Quotient);
        Console.WriteLine("Remainder: {0}", mod.Remainder);
        Console.ReadKey(); // BATCH `pause`
    }
}
```

Comment: Your "optimization tip" is actually not an optimization at all. When the runtime detects that you have a fixed length array being iterated over, it inlines the call to `.Length`. You actually can gain a slight performance benefit because it can also remove bounds checking under certain circumstances.

Comment: Iterating over an array while you're changing the size is generally considered to be a bad programming practice. If you *do* decide to resize it, the new size will be reflected in `Length`.

Comment: I was a bit unclear with that. When I say inline the call, I mean that it places whatever happens when you access `Length` directly at the call site. It's analogous to the inlining of function calls.

Answer (score 1):

0 % 13 = 0

0 / 13 = 0

It's simple mathematics.

Comment: I think I get the modulus now, it just returns the remainder, and if there is no remainder, it returns the number. I guess my next question is how do you divide something like 1 by thirteen? Or two or so on? I appreciate the help btw, but after zero I don't get how you can divide 1 by 13. I could see it as a fractional address, but it still would not equal one. How is it that it could equal a whole address?

Comment: @user 13 goes into 1 zero times, so you have 1 % 13 = 1 - (0 * 13) = 1.

Comment: I am talking about <code> suits[i / 13] </code>. I see how 0/13=0, but what about 1/13?

Comment: 13 goes into 1 zero times because 1 < 13. So 1/13 is truncated to 0. Any number from 0 to 12 will give x/13 = 0.

Comment: I think I see now. So up to thirteen 0 will be the address, next time it reaches a point it can be divided evenly by thirteen, it will go to the next memory address. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't dividing into 0, you are dividing 0 by 13. 0/13 = 0